# How to launch a specific URL with Firefox in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to launch a specific URL using Firefox. But I'm only able to open Firefox browser and not able to launch that URL.

```
class BrowserHelper
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"gecko\\");
    public void Navigate(string url)
    {
        path = path.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path);
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        if (driver == null)
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService);
        }
            driver.Url = url;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(driver.Url);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
}
class Realtest
{
    BrowserHelper BH = new BrowserHelper();
    public void test()
    {
        string search ="apple";
        BH.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search);
    }
}
```

And I can only get this page:
[image]

Here's the final URL I want to launch: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=apple

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @AnkurSingh I'm not able to go into that "apple search" page.

Comment: Can you share your full code? form above code it's not possible to make out what the issue. and do share error trace.

Comment: @AnkurSingh  I just added the full code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why not use driver.navigate().to method?why this replacement   path = path.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

Comment: @Hameed But there's no driver.navigate().to method. Only driver.navigate() or driver.navigate().GoToUrl. I've tried driver.navigate() already. It's still not working. And there's no difference if I delete the path replacement.

Comment: Browser is launching but not loading the URL , is it launching any other URL? if its not loading any other URL at least it should throw some error

Comment: @Pradeephebbar It doesn't launch any URL and it never shows any error. So I'm a bit confused, I don't know where I get wrong.

Comment: @HelloWorld , Can you see URL tab in the browser is surrounded by blue line?

Comment: @HelloWorld , Can you post the Final URL here , i mean after  adding the search keyword...

Comment: @Pradeephebbar The picture shown is what I get after I run the program. There's no URL in the  browser URL tab.  Here's the final URL:https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the below code (in Java), and it's working fine by launching the browser and loading the URL also.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=apple");
```

So I feel the problem is with geckodriver version and FireFox browser installed in your local machine. I would suggest you update FireFox and geckodriver to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a pretty easy solution using the command line with c#.

Simply execute the following command to open a new Firefox Tab with the given URL:

```
start firefox wikipedia.de
```

You can also start a new Firefox instance if you wish:

```
start firefox -new-instance wikipedia.de
```

Last but not least the .Net Code to execute the commands in CLI:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = "/c start firefox wikipedia.de", 
    CreateNoWindow = true, 
    FileName = "CMD.exe"
});
```

There is also a lot of other stuff that can be done with Firefox commandLine paramters. You an find all of them here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options

This also works with chrome and opera, simply call

```
start opera wikipedia.de
```

instead of firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to set `driver.Url`, remove that line.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Also, if you simply want to launch a single URL without interacting with the page, then Selenium is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already removed that line. But I get the same result.