# please solve the query of selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the website of my company. I have installed everything.

- java 1.8.161
- firefox 56.0
- chrome 64.0

[image]

I'm trying to launch the browsers:

**1. problem with firefox browser:**  firefox browser is not getting opened and I'm getting this error in console window

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: ull,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1469556455000,"updateDate":1469556455000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21899,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true} 1517982678083  addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} 1517982678088  DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
```

**2. problem with chrome:**- chrome browser is getting launched successfully. but when I try to type "driver." it is not showing me the option like `driver.manage.window.maximize()` option and all that

Comment: For your second Problem: Java is case sensitive. (`Driver` != `driver`)

Comment: This might help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363881/how-to-launch-a-specific-url-with-firefox-in-c-sharp/48365203#48365203

Comment: if you add the code , we can look into the 2nd issue

Answer (score 0):

Respective version of selenium is compatible with certain Firefox version, Please check for the version of Selenium and its compatibility with firefox version.
For Example : Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0 works with Firefox 46.0. You can find the the mentioned version at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Screenshot it's a Typo mistake for Case sensitive

you declare and initialize as   **Driver**

But you are using **driver**