# Latest chromedriver 2.35 and chrome browser 64 showing error in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver 2.35 and chrome browser 64 and selenium 3.9.
My script was working but now its showing error ...
browser launch and just closed..

my script is

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Users//vikas//Downloads//chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

error log :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef) on port 44554
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.89 seconds
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
System info: host: 'vikass-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.1.1.234', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363881/how-to-launch-a-specific-url-with-firefox-in-c-sharp/48365203#48365203

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem today. Updated to *latest* chrome 64 (some updates came even though it was 64 already) and it started working. But now I have several tests crashing with weird timeouts. Perhaps need to update Selenium as well...

Comment: P.S.: my timeouts issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2241

Answer (score 0):

Please check the compatible Selenium webdriver and use the following code and try:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users//vikas//Downloads//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
String path = "D:\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Tried this but same error.. My same script was running before but I don't know what updated on my system and showing error