# Why URL is displayed in Orange color (in address bar of firefox) when selenium launches it

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

I don't know why the URL (ex: google) is displayed in orange color when selenium launches it in firefox 56.0.2 (64 bit). Any idea/help/pointer ??

1. TestNG: 6.13
2. selenium-java : 3.6.0
3. apache-maven-3.5.2
4. firefox 56.0.2 (64 bit)

[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90CmZ.png)(image is attached here)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365203/7877196 this might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a default behaviour for FF to show that browser is controled by webdriver (or other remote software)